# springboot causing 2phase transaction commit when not needed

Tags: jboss, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a standalone application A that invokes a webservice  B deployed in jboss eap 6.2.3. the application in jboss uses a mysql datasource. This application integration is working very well.

I needed to webify the standalone application itself into a spring rest data jpa microservice
So I wrote a spring boot wrapper for that standalone application A. It runs in an embedded tomcat and invokes the aplpication B running in jboss.
I also ported some configurations logic from properties files into a embedded h2 database.

Now at places I am seeing this exception shown below for insert into the mysql by the application B inside jboss. My guess is what was a simple transaction earlier and working well has now become a 2 phase commit that sometimes fails.
How to prevent this?

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Could not prepare. 
    at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:70) [infinispan-core-5.2.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:5.2.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.prepare(TransactionCoordinator.java:161) [infinispan-core-5.2.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:5.2.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.prepare(TransactionCoordinator.java:123) [infinispan-core-5.2.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:5.2.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:68) [infinispan-core-5.2.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:5.2.7.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to comment.  Are you saying that the exception occurs in application `B` (not `A`, which you are actually upgrading)?  Also, the exception originates in Infinispan.  Are you using it for caching in application `B`?  Please post the code and configuration for the operation where this error occurs.  Also see [this document](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Using+Infinispan+as+JPA-Hibernate+Second+Level+Cache+Provider) for configuring Infinispan for correct usage with transactional code.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot has out-of-the-box support for JTA. When it runs in an environment where a JTA transaction manager is available, it uses that rather than creating a local transaction manager for your data store. If that's not what you want, you can disable jta support by adding `spring.jta.enabled=false` to your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.Will be useful in some scenarios.
However after posting I realised the flaw in the question.

standalone application A
webified application(even if a microservice runninging embeddedtomcat ) say A1

Both are actually just rest clients to rest services running in  a webservice B deployed in jboss eap 6.2.3..

A and A1 might as well be replaced by just a simple human visitor visting from a browser the application B.

I dont think A or A1 can influence the transactions in any ways for B.
Right?

Anyways the problem was due to the closeness to B of the application A1.
The actual problem was related to a cluster event for the cluster in which B was deployed and triggering of it by A1. A bit complicated scenario. The only problem was that the insert was being attempted  too soon before the cluster change event could even reach.

Comment: Or do you suggest that somehow they will be in a a distributed tx.I dont think so. Do write if thts possible. Howeveras I said the problemin this case was different